# Is it possible to set a pending breakpoint in the solaris modular debugger (mdb)

Tags: debugging, solaris

I'm trying to debug a function in 3rd party shared library.  I'm having a hard time setting a breakpoint in the function as the application dies shortly after loading the library.  Does anyone know of a way to set a pending break-point in mdb so the breakpoint is set shortly after the library is loaded?

Mustafa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call *pending breakpoint* is called *deferred breakpoint* in `mdb`; the way it's being used is like this:

```
$ mdb /bin/ls
> ::bp libc.so.1`_init
> :r
mdb: stop at libc.so.1`_init
mdb: target stopped at:
libc.so.1`_init:save      %sp, -0x60, %sp
```

I.e. just turn the `::bp` command around, `<addr>::bp` is direct (and requires the symbol / address to be present, already loaded), while `` ::bp <object`symbol> `` is deferred (and activated by the debugger when the specified object is first loaded). Using the `` object`symbol `` notation you can distinguish between identically-named functions in different libraries even:

```
> !ldd /bin/ls
        libsec.so.1 =>   /lib/libsec.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libavl.so.1 =>   /lib/libavl.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
> ::bp libsec.so.1`_init
> ::bp libc.so.1`_init
> ::bp libavl.so.1`_init
> ::bp libm.so.2`_init
> ::bp _init
> :r
mdb: stop at libc.so.1`_init
mdb: target stopped at:
libc.so.1`_init:save      %sp, -0x60, %sp
> :c
mdb: stop at libavl.so.1`_init
mdb: target stopped at:
libavl.so.1`_init:      save      %sp, -0x60, %sp
> :c
mdb: stop at libsec.so.1`_init
mdb: target stopped at:
libsec.so.1`_init:      save      %sp, -0x60, %sp
> :c
mdb: stop at _init
mdb: target stopped at:
_init:          save      %sp, -0x60, %sp
```

Enjoy debugging !

Comment: Thanks man!  You helped save countless hours of wasted debugging time.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite figure out how to do set a pending breakpoint but I found that getting the name of the last library loaded, helped.  To do this I added a system breakpoint on the 'open' system call and I added a command to the breakpoint which prints the first argument to open (i.e. the name of the file) and continues.

```
> ::sysbp -c "<i0 /s; ::cont" open
> ::cont
```